# Dynamic View on SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, wss-3.0, fast-for-sharepoint, wss

I want to create a dynamic view on my list. The list is filtered based on the current users' information coming from an external database i.e. based on which user is logged in, a value is fetched from external database and based on that value i want my SharePoint list to be filtered.

How can i do this. I am newbie in SharePoint. Any help would be really great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use C# to find out what username to filter for you could try to use the [Filter Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms546894%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to filter a standard XSLTListViewWebPart. It should accept FilterName and FilterValue. If you can't use the built in Filter Web Part you could [write your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457205%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Another option is to refresh the page with the query string for this, like:

```
?FilterField1=AssignedTo&FilterValue1=Eirik%20Brandtzæg
```

Noet that this does not work for wildcards, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I used the custom filter web part method to achieve my result.